# google map does not appear on contact page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have facing problem to insert google map in my website i have inset code below...

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script> 
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD0jH85l0hZ_tNF6zl35997Nb6HXLj9YYI'></script>
<div style='overflow:hidden;height:471px;width:100%;'>
<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:471px;width:100%;'></div>
  <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
</div> 
<a href='https://embedmaps.net'>www.embedmaps.net</a> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=370cd4178fedb6711b4163f7e3b23f5bc71df81c'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function init_map(){
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(26.169595,91.7563156),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.169595,91.7563156)
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<strong>NEWS Travel Services (India) </strong><br>Choudhury Bhawan, House No.33,  Borthakur Mill Road, Ulubari<br>781007 Guwahati <br>'});
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

live url of site is http://www.newstravelservices.com/

Comment: live url of page is http://www.newstravelservices.com/

Comment: What is the issue?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, along with a description of what the issue is.

Comment: You're loading the Maps API twice, which won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
```

You're also loading the Maps API in with this line:

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD0jH85l0hZ_tNF6zl35997Nb6HXLj9YYI'></script>
```

Having it duplicated will generally stop it working. That second one is probably better, given it's including your API key.